# auto_now_add fields override my input

Tags: python, django, django-models

Given a model

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

When I do

```
my_foo = Foo.objects.create(bar=yesterday)
```

Then `my_bar.foo` is not yesterday but now. I have to do

```
my_foo = Foo.objects.create()
my_foo.bar = yesterday
my_foo.save()
```

This didn't use to be the case, but is true for Django 1.8.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add):

> The auto_now and auto_now_add options will always use the date in the default timezone at the moment of creation or update. If you need something different, you may want to consider simply using your own callable default or overriding save() instead of using auto_now or auto_now_add; or using a DateTimeField instead of a DateField and deciding how to handle the conversion from datetime to date at display time.

So you should do that instead

```
bar = models.DateTimeField(default=date.today)
```

Comment: Right... Looking around the web, it seems that these kwargs have changed functionality so many times that people just recomment not using them altogether. I will move towards overriding the `save` instead

Comment: @Eldamir - I can't find anywhere in the docs that suggest it has ever changed, this note is even present in the [docs for 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) - The only reference to it at all is a [bugfix in 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#loading-some-incomplete-fixtures-no-longer-works)

Comment: I only suggest to use: DateTimeField: default=timezone.now - from django.utils.timezone.now() - as suggestet in [docs 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)