# Django how to over ride created date

Tags: python, django, django-models

We have a base model that sets a created and modified field:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(_('modified'), auto_now=True)
    ... other default properties

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

We use this class to extend our models:

```
class Event(BaseModel):
```

Is there a way to over ride the created date when creating new Events?

This is a stripped down version of our code. We are sending an array of event objects containing a created timestamp in our request payload. After the objects are added to the db, the created property is set to now and not the value from the payload.

I would like to still extend from the BaseModel as other areas of the code may not explicitly set a created value, in which case it should default to now.

```
events = []
for e in payload['events']:
    event = Event(
       created=datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(e['created'])
       name='foo'
    )
    events.append(event)
Event.objects.bulk_create(events)
```

Comment: `BaseModel` is an `abstract = True` model?

Comment: I think that your response is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42219989/14541937

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes it is abstract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `created` field for your `Event` model with:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Event(BaseModel):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

If you do not want this to show up for `ModelForm`s and `ModelAdmin`s by default, you can make use of [**`editable=False`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable):

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Event(BaseModel):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=False)
```